# xmlhttprequest and serversocket in Android

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, serversocket

My experience on web technologies aren't good so I want to know if this is possible from you experts.

Can a serversocket in Android respond to a xmlhttprequest?
What I'd want to do is, assuming my PC and my Android are on the same network, can I make a xmlhttprequest from my browser to my Android, and have the Android (running a serversocket service) receive and extract whatever I sent through the xmlhttprequest? Say a text command.

Is this possible or have I gotten this all wrong?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.  Have a look at iJetty for starters: http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

Comment: Thank you dbryson. I will have a look in it. Seems a little complicated than I thought.